# 2 classes (1 VM 1 service) changing/accessing a property in a singleton class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So i'm trying to use my "mediator" class as an in-between for my service and my VM when it comes to a couple of booleans.

In my mediator, we have this:

```
    private bool isAddGroupChecked = false;
    public bool IsAddGroupChecked
    {
        get { return isAddGroupChecked; }
        set
        {
            isAddGroupChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My service retrieves/changes this value by doing the following (for changing)

```
ActionMediator.Instance.IsAddGroupChecked = false;
```

My VM can have that boolean changed through the view and has the following property:

```
    public ActionMediator ActionMediator
    {
        get { return ActionMediator.Instance; }
    }

    public bool IsAddGroupChecked
    {
        get { return ActionMediator.IsAddGroupChecked; }
        set
        {
            ActionMediator.IsAddGroupChecked = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsAddGroupChecked);
        }
    }
```

Problem is, when you click the toggle (`isAddGroupChecked`) the value on the singleton changes to `True` correctly. However, when my service changes the value (say back to false), the VM isn't being notified of that..... where am I going wrong? I'm doing this so my service and VM are not coupled to eachother by this....

Comment: Was there any reason this was downvoted? If so, could whoever downvoted state why they did so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `PropertyChanged` event from your singleton has not been assigned on your VM, and that is why it is not being notified, as your service will change the status on the singleton, not on the VM.

So you have (at least) three options

1. Hanlde the `PropertyChanged` event from your singleton on your VM to change your VM state.

```cs
public VM()
{
    ActionMediator.Instance.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Mediator_PropertyChanged);
}

private void Mediator_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsAddGroupChecked")
        this.IsAddGroupChecked = ActionMediator.Instance.IsAddGroupChecked;
}
```

If you go for this one, it is also a good idea to modify you mediator to avoid looping

```cs
private bool isAddGroupChecked = false;
public bool IsAddGroupChecked
{
    get { return isAddGroupChecked; }
    set
    {
        if (value != isAddGroupChecked)
        {
            isAddGroupChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Give an instance of your VM to your service so it can change the state directly (not a good idea though)
3. Remove the `IsAddGroupChecked` property from your VM and bind your view directly to `ActionMediator.IsAddGroupChecked`

Comment: The third option seems plausible... Is one better than the other between option 1 and option 3?

Comment: I would try the third one. It is more straightforward.